# Copy lines from one file to another in Linux excluding comments

Tags: linux, sed, copy, comments, line

How do I copy lines from one file to another in Linux without opening source and destination files and I need to exclude the comments when copying the lines.

I do not want to copy the comments in the first file and the files are in different locations

Comment: You need to provide more details. What is the comment delimiter?  `#`?   Does the comment delimiter always occur at the first character of a line?

Comment: The comment delimiter is # it starts at beginning of the line

Answer (score 0):

Assuming lines are commented with `#` at the very beginning of each line, the following should work:

```
grep -v "^#" path/to/input/file >path/to/output/file
```

(Note: This will either create a new output file or irreversibly overwrite the output file if it already exists)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming comment lines in your file contain `#` at the beginning of each line, the following `sed` command will delete these lines:

```
$ sed '/^#/d' path/to/input-file > path/to/output-file
```

If your file can also contain lines with whitespace before the `#`, the following `sed` command will delete lines beginning with zero or more spaces or tabs (in any order), followed by a hash (`#`) character:

```
$ sed '/^[ \t]*#/d' path/to/input-file > path/to/output-file
```

If your file also contains lines containing code followed by a comment, the following `sed` command should work:

```
$ sed -e '/^[ \t]*#/d' -e 's/#.*$//' path/to/input-file > path/to/output-file
```